# Ignore .gitconfig when cloning repository with NodeGit

Tags: javascript, git, coffeescript, git-config, nodegit

I'm trying to use [NodeGit](http://www.nodegit.org/) to download some tutorials for my application from private repositories. I'm using a token to authenticate and download them via https. The problem is, if user has set

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

in `.gitconfig`, it will fail with **callback returned unsupported credentials type** error. I tried using [Config](http://www.nodegit.org/api/config/) API, but not sure if I was doing this correctly, because there is no description for this in docs.

Here is my code:

```
fse     = require 'fs-extra'
Git     = require 'nodegit'

...

cloneOpts =
    fetchOpts:
        callbacks:
            certificateCheck: => 1
            credentials: (url, userName) =>
                return Git.Cred.userpassPlaintextNew(myUser, myToken)
            transferProgress: (stats) =>
                p = (stats.receivedObjects() + stats.indexedObjects()) / (stats.totalObjects() * 2)
                try
                    progress p
                catch error
                    console.log error
fse.remove dstPath, (err) =>
    Git.Clone(tutorial.uri, dstPath, cloneOpts)
        .then((repo) =>
            console.log 'success')
        .catch((error) =>
            console.log error.message)
```

How can I make NodeGit ignore users' `.gitconfig`?